# Managing inter instance access on EC2

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

We are in the process of setting up our IT infrastructure on Amazon EC2.
Assume a setup along the lines of:
X production servers
Y staging servers
Log collation and Monitoring Server
Build Server
Obviously we have a need to have various servers talk to each other. A new build needs to be scp'd over to a staging server. The Log collator needs to pull logs from production servers. We are quickly realizing we are running into trouble managing access keys. Each server has its own key pair and possibly its own security group. We are ending up copying *.pem files over from server to server kind of making a mockery of security. The build server has the access keys of the staging servers in order to connect via ssh and push a new build. The staging servers similarly has access keys of the production instances (gulp!)
I did some extensive searching on the net but couldnt really find anyone talking about a sensible way to manage this issue. How are people with a setup similar to ours handling this issue? We know our current way of working is wrong. The question is - what is the right way ?
Appreciate your help!
Thanks

[Update]
Our situation is complicated by the fact that at least the build server needs to be accessible from an external server (specifically, github). We are using Jenkins and the post commit hook needs a publicly accessible URL. The bastion approach suggested by @rook fails in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

A very good method of handling access to a collection of EC2 instances is using a [Bastion Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host).

All machines you use on EC2 should disallow SSH access to the open internet,  except for the Bastion Host.   Create a new security policy called "Bastion Host",  and only allow port 22 incoming from the bastion to all other EC2 instances.   All keys used by your EC2 collection are housed on the bastion host.  Each user has their own account to the bastion host.   These users should authenticate to the bastion using a password protected key file.  Once they login they should have access to whatever keys they need to do their job.  When someone is fired you remove their user account to the bastion.  If a user copies keys from the bastion,  it won't matter because they can't login unless they are first logged into the bastion.

Comment: @anand - This will still work in one of two ways: 1) The GitHub post commit hook uses HTTPS, thus is unaffected by all things SSH, if you'd simply choose to open port 443 for Jenkins (but read on). 2) Even better would be to stick to Rook's suggestion for this as well, which requires a reverse proxy setup for the build server on the bastion host though; this might be both easy or a bit involved depending on the environment, but the GitHub plugin is prepared for this, see [Jenkins inside a firewall](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin#GithubPlugin-Jenkinsinsideafirewall).

Comment: excellent. I currently have the reverse proxy on my Jenkins server itself - hadnt thought of pushing that into the bastion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create two set of keypairs, one for your staging servers and one for your production servers. You can give you developers the staging keys and keep the production keys private.

I would put the new builds on to S3 and have a perl script running on the boxes to pull the lastest code from your S3 buckets and install them on to the respective servers. This way, you dont have to manually scp all the builds into it everytime. You can also automate this process using some sort of continuous build automation tools that would build and dump the build on to you S3 buckets respectively. Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks - we are already in the process of automating the push out from the build machine to a staging environment (S3 or otherwise). For various reasons, we would like to avoid a polling script running on a production machine. Also, your approach will still mean pushing the staging server keys to every production instance. We would be uncomfortable creating an AMI with SSH keys embedded in it. So the multiple copies of keys issue is not solved